# Can I stop SQL*Plus from displaying "connected" when I have a "connect" in a script?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a few sql scripts that I need to run via SQL*Plus. These
scripts connect several times as different users with a `connect user_01/pass_01@db_01`. Now, each time the script does such a connect, it confirms the successful connection with a `connected`. This is distracting and I want to turn it off.

I can achieve what I want with a

```
set termout off
connect user_01/pass_01@db_01
set termout on
```

Is there a more elegant solution to my problem?

Note, it doesn't help to permanently `set termout off` at the start of the script since I need to know if a command didn't run successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tip I've used from Tom Kyte's book (forget which one). I have a script called connect.sql in my sqlplus directory:

```
set termout off 
connect &1 
@login
```

and in my glogin.sql I've added this:

```
select lower(user) || '@' || 
substr( global_name,1, decode( dot, 0, length(global_name), dot-1) ) 
global_name 
from (select global_name, instr(global_name,'.') dot from global_name );

set sqlprompt '&gname> '

set termout on
```

then I call

```
@connect user_01/pass_01@db_01
```

instead of

```
connect user_01/pass_01@db_01
```

Comment: Seems this is the closest I can get.

Answer (score 0):

If it really bothers you you could try

```
SQL> set feedback off
SQL> alter session set current_schema=SCOTT;
```

But this may not meet your needs ....

Comment: Thanks! And yes, it doesn't meet my needs.